# Is a torrent tracker actually required if things like DHT exist?

Tags: bittorrent, p2p

Why should I still be using torrent trackers to distribute files via BitTorrent if DHT exists?

I'm wanting to build a small website where I can distribute torrents containing non-copyrighted media that I've collected.

This is the first time I've created my own torrents, and I want to make them properly so that they're future proof for years to come.

My dilemma is that I'm not sure whether to run my own torrent tracker with a whitelist, utilise the many free open bittorrent trackers that are out there, or if I even need to use torrent trackers at all to distribute my files. Things like DHT seem to be common place in torrent clients now, and although I don't fully understand how DHT works, it seems to replace trackers entirely(?).

Comment: Trackers aren't needed, but known hosts to bootstrap the DHT process are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that torrent trackers are no longer absolutely required.  See [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332107/how-does-dht-in-torrents-work) for great information.